# How to use a string in one UIViewController from another view controller?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I am trying to use a `UITextField` named `nameTF` in first `UIViewController` and use `nameTF.text` to set it to another `UITextField` named `secondNameTF.text` in the second `UIViewController`. How should I go about doing so?

Comment: how do you move to other view controller ? Do you present it modally or present it by segue ?

Answer (score 0):

Set it in `prepareForSegue`. You need a variable in the second view controller to hold the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need have a variable set on the other VC to receive the string. You need to declare it on other VC .h file

```
  @property (weak, nonatomic)  NSString *descriptionLabel;
```

and in your current VC, you do this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"test"]){

    DetailViewController *vc=[segue destinationViewController];

    [vc setDescriptionLabel:_textField.text];
    }

}
```

Also make sure you also name the segue as test!!!!!